# PHP - multiple different databases dependency injected class

Tags: php, database, oop, dependency-injection

I've spent the last several hours trying to find an answer to the "best", most logical, etc way to write a php database class to simultaneously connect to one postgresql db and one mysql db.  Also, I'd like to adopt a Dependency Injection design but am new to that whole concept.

So far I've come up with...

```
class Database {

    public function PgSqlConnect() {
            /* Connect to database */
        $host = 'localhost';
        $dbname = '---';
        $user = '---';
        $pass = '---';
        $timeout = 5;   /* seconds */

        try {
            $pgsql_dbh = new PDO("pgsql:host=$host; dbname=$dbname", $user, $pass); 
            $pgsql_dbh->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_TIMEOUT, $timeout ); 
            $pgsql_dbh->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );

            return $pgsql_dbh;
        } catch( PDOException $e ) {
            echo 'Unable to connect to database: ' . $e->getMessage();
        }
    }


    public function MySqlConnect() {
            /* Connect to database */
        $host = 'localhost';
        $dbname = '---';
        $user = '---';
        $pass = '---';
        $timeout = 5;   /* seconds */

        try {
            $mysql_dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$host; dbname=$dbname", $user, $pass); 
            $mysql_dbh->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_TIMEOUT, $timeout ); 
            $mysql_dbh->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );

            return $mysql_dbh;
        } catch( PDOException $e ) {
            echo 'Unable to connect to database: ' . $e->getMessage();
        }
    }

}
```

Obviously the duplicated code violates the DRY approach.  I know and have seen many examples of multiple db connections, but most deal with same driver and don't provide DI capability.

I should also add that I've considered placing the connection details into the Database class constructor as...

```
$driver = 'mysql';
...
$mysqldb = new Database($driver,$un,$pw,...);

$driver = 'pgsql';
...
$pgsqldb = new Database($driver,$un,$pw,...);
```

but I don't know if that is really a good idea nor how well it would work with DI.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 8):

You should create an interface first for all the DB operations.

```
interface IDatabase
{
    function connect();
    function query();
    ...
}
```

Then have different driver classes implementing this interface

```
class MySQLDB implements IDatabase
{
}
class PGSQLDB implements IDatabase
{
}
```

This way you can easily use dependency injection.

```
class Test
{
   private $db;

   function __construct(IDatabase $db)
   {
        $this->db = $db;
   }
}
```

You can call it as:

```
$mysqldb = new MySQLDB();
$test = new Test($mysqldb);
or
$pgsqldb = new PGSQLDB();
$test = new Test($pgsqldb);
```

Comment: Thanks Vikk, Could you clarify how if I put the PDO connection code in IDatabase::connect then how will it discern which PDO driver to use?

Comment: The interface will not (and can not) have any code except functions and their signatures. It's the concrete classes (i.e. MySqlDB) which will implement these function. So in MySQLDB's connect() function, you will write connection code for MySQL and in PGSQLDB's connect() function, you will write connection code for PGSQL

Comment: I see that now.  So I'll just have duplicated code in each concrete class?

Comment: To avoid duplicated code you can extend an abstract class. Or wait for php 5.4 and use traits.

Comment: @Vikk Can you tell me why you have the interface?  Is that so yo ucan pass any class without having to know the class ahead of time, as long as it implements IDatabase?  Could it have been done without an interface?

Answer (score 2):

To avoid duplicated code you can extend an abstract class

```
abstract class AbstractDb {
    public function connect() {
        // common code to avoid duplication
        echo 'connected!';
    }

    abstract public function escapeField();
    abstract public function escapeValue();
}

class MySQL extends AbstractDb {
    public function escapeField() {
        // Db-specific method
    }

    public function escapeValue() {
        // Db-specific method
    }
}

$db = new MySQL;
$db->connect();
```

Or use composition, and let the Db class use a different driver for db-specific methods

```
interface IDriver {
    public function escapeField();
    public function escapeValue();
}

class MySQLDriver implements IDriver {
    public function escapeField() {
        // Db-specific method
    }

    public function escapeValue() {
        // Db-specific method
    }
}

class Db {
    public function __construct($driver) {
        $this->driver = $driver;
    }

    public function connect() {
        // common code here ? idk, it's just an example
        echo 'connect!';
    }

    // this method is db-specific, so we call the driver
    public function escapeField($field) {
        return $this->driver->escapeField($field);
    }

    public function escapeValue() {
        // same here
    }
}

$db = new Db(new MySQLDriver);
$db->connect();
```

In php 5.4 there will be traits, so there will be more approaches to avoid code duplication.

Comment: I think I understand your approach, but I'm not trying to write an abstraction, since I'm using PDO.  I'd simply like to encapsulate db code without duplicating the entire method for each db connection when the only code that changes is the driver string.  I've appended an example of what I'm currently considering to the end of my question.  Would you recommend passing a db type through the constructor into the class?  Would you still abstract the class or use an interface?

Comment: First of all, PDO brings very little abstraction, it's not a DBAL. Anyway, if you put the connection options inside your constructor, you are hardcoding them (not desirable). If you use a driver instead, in the future you could add more drivers without changing your Database class. That approach is more decoupled, maintainable, and testable. But if you just need a quick fix, your solution is ok for your problem, even when it's not a good solution in general terms of software design.

Comment: Another option would be using something that already exists, like [Doctrine 2 DBAL](http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/dbal/2.1/en/). I didn't mention it before because I assumed you were trying to learn and build your own implementation.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean to imply that PDO provides abstraction.  Only that PDO will sufice for my needs without adding full abstraction.

Comment: You are correct in your assumption that I'm trying to learn and build my own.  I much appreciate you taking the time to help me understand.