# Problems connecting to MySQL using PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I've been trying to convert my application from using the depreciated mysql syntax to PDO for connecting to the database and performing queries, and it's been a pain so far.

Right now I have a class, db_functions.php, in which I'm trying to create a PDO connection to the database, as well as perform all the CRUD operations inside of.

Here is a sampling of the code:

```
db_functions.php
<?php

class DB_Functions {

    private $db;

    // constructor
    function __construct() {
        require_once 'config.php';
        // connecting to mysql
        try {
        $this->$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=gcm', DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
        }
        catch (PDOException $e) {
            $output = 'Unable to connect to database server.' .
            $e->getMessage();
            exit();
        }
    }

    // destructor
    function __destruct() {

    }

public function getAllUsers() {
    try {
    $sql = "select * FROM gcm_users";
    //$result = mysql_query("select * FROM gcm_users");
    $result = $this->$db->query($sql);
    return $result;
    }
    catch (PDOException $e) {
        $error = 'Error getting all users: ' . $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

With that code, i'm getting the following error:

```
Notice: Undefined variable: db in C:\xampp\htdocs\gcm\db_functions.php on line 12

Fatal error: Cannot access empty property in C:\xampp\htdocs\gcm\db_functions.php on line 12
```

Line 12 is:

```
 $this->$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=gcm', DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
```

How could I fix this so that I have a proper instance of a `PDO` connection to my database that I can use to create queries in other methods in `db_functions`, such as `getAllUsers()`

I used the answer found at [How do I create a connection class with dependency injection and interfaces?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12183819/how-do-i-create-a-connection-class-with-dependency-injection-and-interfaces) to no avail.

Comment: Do `$this->db` instead of `$this->$db` - That [**link you provided**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12183819/how-do-i-create-a-connection-class-with-dependency-injection-and-interfaces) specifically states `$this->pdo = new PDO( '...');` without the `$` in front of `pdo`, so do the same here.

Comment: Thanks, that seemed to work. I'm curious as to why you don't use the '$' symbol in front of it, since db is still referring to a variable, correct?

Comment: because you working in a class and classes working with objects. its not actually a variable. so its a object. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## TYPO

```
//$this->$db = 
$this->db =
```

same here

```
//$this->$db->query($sql);
$this->db->query($sql);
```

and i also would use `127.0.0.1` instead of `localhost` to improve the performance otherwise making a connection will take very long... a couple of seconds just for connection...