# Drop down form list with MySQL

Tags: php, html, mysql

so I want to make a drop down list in my form but rather than manually writing the options in the form I want to link it to my database.

HTML

```
<form>
<select name="fruit">
  <option value="apple">Apples</option>
  <option value="banana">Bananas</option>
  <option value="pear">Pears</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

This is what I have so far but I want to exclude the option values and replace them with existing records in my database. How do I do this in PHP?

I know I will be using something like, but I'm not sure

```
$results = $pdo->query('SELECT * FROM fruit');
            foreach ($results as $row)
```

Thanks for the help :)

Comment: It sounds like a school assignment. You should be able to figure this out with any of the myriad PHP tutorials available online. And if you're new to PHP programming, read this http://webdeveloper.gdemolished.com/stop-building-shitty-php-web-applications/

Comment: Basically, you need to: 1) Connect to your DB, 2) Execute your query, 3) Fetch the result and using `foreach` print it `echo "<option...." . $result . "</option>"`. Everything is very easy to google, I don't think someone should just write you the code.

Comment: @akasummer there is always one that cannot resist

Comment: @Bob, Have you already created `php` file with `PDO` connection object ?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest yeah there's a separate file that's linked to my database so I don't have to keep re-writing the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<form>
<select name="fruit">
<?php
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=database", 'username', 'password', array( PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8"));
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

$results = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM fruit");
while($row = $results->fetch( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC )){ 
?>
<option value="<?= $row['id'] ?>"><?= $row['fruitname'] ?></option>
<?php
}
?>
</select>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

This should give you a basic idea of how to do this.

Comment: Actually, I didn't. But I just caught an error and fixed it. But this is how I would do it.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your `fruit` table has `name` field:

```
<form>
<select name="fruit">
<?php 
    $results = $pdo->query('SELECT * FROM fruit');
    foreach ($results as $row):
?>
  <option value="<?php $row['name']?>"><?php ucfirst($row['name']) . "s"; ?></option>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</select>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score -1):

In your case this is the solution:

```
<form>
    <select name="fruits" class="form-control">
    <?php
    $results = $pdo->query('SELECT * FROM fruit');
    foreach ($results as $row)
    {
     ?><option value="<?= $row['id'] ?>"><?= $row['fruitname'] ?></option><?php
    }
    ?>
    </select>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Stick to the question, dont invent stuff that is only going to confuse the questioner just because you have a bit of vaguely similiar code lying around

Comment: Not sure why your getting downvotes, I believe your answer answers the question.

Comment: Look again @Grumpy in what way does this code resemble that in the question. Does the questioner have a function called `getAllUsers()`

Comment: @RiggsFolly i use my snippets because is the same situation.. u downvote my solution ? ok... but I think , that this is not confused.

Comment: @RiggsFolly The question asks how to populate a dropdown list with php from a database, and rdn's answer does that. Though I do agree he should have left out the array part.

Comment: @RiggsFolly he can use getAllFruits()... and can edit my snippets....

Comment: Not my downvote btw, but I have to agree with @RiggsFolly - `getAllUsers()` is ambiguous to the question and unknowing if they know what to do with that. *"in **my** case getAllUsers() return array of Users."* - Sure, in ***"your"*** case.

Comment: @rdn87 OP is asking how to get data from DB and display it. You hid all retrieval behind your `getAllUsers()` function, put too much specific details, which are not related to question. Plus your `?>`, `<?` tags placement is just head exploding for me.

Comment: `public function getAllUsers()` Seems awfully close to an answer given here http://stackoverflow.com/q/24253898/

Comment: Ouch! I would hate to have to try and debug any of your code `?><option value="<?= $row['id'] ?>"><?= $row['fruitname'] ?></option><?php` this may work but pity the poor developer that needs to mod it